# On Kali, by default terminal starts with root privileges, how to stop that?

Tags: kali-linux, login

On other distros when I open terminal, it is usually either ask for password or logs in with normal user priviliges, in Kali it logs on automatically with root.
I want to stop that.

Comment: That's why Kali is for advanced.

Comment: what do you mean ? it is not doable ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Kali Linux Root User Policy](https://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-root-user-policy):

> Kali Linux, however, as a security and auditing platform, contains many which tools can only run with root privileges. Further, Kali Linux’s nature makes its use in a multi-user environment highly unlikely.
>
> For these reasons, the default Kali user is “root”, and no non-privileged user is created as a part of the installation process. **This is one reason that Kali Linux is not recommended for use by Linux beginners who might be more apt to make destructive mistakes while running with root privileges.**

To create a non-root account, use `useradd` with the appropriate options.  Then set the user's password using `passwd`.  See the manuals for these two utilities.  For further Kali-specific information, refer to the official Kali Linux documentation website at https://docs.kali.org/